# RXJS: caching result for a specific argument

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

How do I say in RXJS: "save the last five calculations of the function `timesTwo = (value: number) => value * 2`"? So if the stream gets 1,2,3,4,5,6,2 the result (4) for the second "2" is not calculated but retrieved from cache?

I assume I have to use `publishReplay( )` for this but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm assuming your function call is expensive — is the return type a future value like a `Promise` or `Observable`?

Comment: no but I can easily put it in the next() of an Observable

Comment: Oh, so the operation isn't asynchronous? It makes more sense to do this caching synchronously if so.